# Equivalent for uops_dispatched_port and uops_executed_port on AMD

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, perf, amd-processor, avx512

I am working on the activity of ensuring optimal loading of CPU pipeline by FMA operations.
I need to make measurements on AMD Ryzen 9 (Zen 4), not the Intel platform.

Could you suggest HW events or a Linux-based tool showing how many uops are executed on CPU execution ports?